# iPad won’t connect to some apps online

Tags: ipad, wifi, internet

iPad Pro (11-inch) (2nd generation) on 14.2 (18B92) gives a "cannot connect" error on many apps, but not all.

It will connect to:

- Local WiFi.
- Stack Exchange.
- Mail.
- Safari.
- App Store.

It will *not* connect to:

- Facebook
- Covet
- Ookla Speedtest
- Merge Mansion

or even Apple Support (see error below).

[image: Error message]

<sup>*Cannot connect to Apple Support.  You must connect to a Wi-Fi or cellular data network to access Apple Support.*</sup>

Any suggestions why some apps see the Internet and some don’t?

Already tried:

- Reset WiFi on iPad.
- Reset Network Settings on iPad.
- Reset Xfinity Gateway.
- Power down and restart iPad.

Comment: Husband here. Apps are working on her iPhone, just not her iPad.

Comment: Have you verified the IP address and other network settings under Settings -> Wi-Fi -> (little i icon next to your network)? Based on the screenshot you shared, the iPad  does not appear to be connected to a wifi network at all.

Comment: It is connected to WiFi. It has no cellular, it’s only connection is WiFi and it posted this question.

Comment: Do you have any ad or website blockers installed in the iPad?  It looks like the sites are being blocked by an ad blocker.

Comment: No blockers installed.

Answer (score 2):

Removed the VPN that she did not remember installing and the problem went away.